# Cython: public functions and segmentation fault

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, cython, public

Trying to harness the feature of public functions and classes in cython I immediately ran into a problem with simplest things. Two days of googling and reading the forums yielded no result. Documentation says kinda: "just use it, and it will work". Ok.

**public.pxd:**

```
# cython: language_level=3
```

**public.pyx:**

```
cdef public void Qu():
    print("Qu!")
```

**public_c.c:**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "public.h"

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyInit_public();

    printf("Init\n");

    Qu();

    printf("Finalize\n");

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

**compile.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

cython public.pyx
gcc -fPIC $(python3-config --cflags) -c public.c -o public.o
gcc -fPIC $(python3-config --cflags) -c public_c.c -o public_c.o
gcc public_c.o public.o $(python3-config --ldflags) -lpython3.9 -o public_c
```

---

No errors or warnings during compilation. Cython generated .c and .h files look ok. But...

```
$ ./public_c
Init
Segmentation fault
```

Even this simplest try fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Documentation says "In Python 3.x, calling the module init function directly should be avoided" and recommends the initab mechanism

Comment: Thanks. I missed that part of documentation.
Inittab procedure solved the problem.